# Query for getting readers who borrowed ALL books

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to help with this problem I never experienced before. I need to get readers who borrowed ALL of the books in table Book.

Thank you for your help.

Tables:

```
Reader (id, name, address, birthdate, contact)
Book (isbn, title, publisher, recomended_price)
BookCopy (copy_no, price, year, Book_isbn)
BookLoans (id, date_of_borrow, date_of_return, Reader_id, BookCopy_copy_no)
```

Comment: Hi Banik and be welcome. Is that a homework ?

Comment: No. I'm learning for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this script work or not. If not, Please add some sample data for each table and your expected output.

```
SELECT R.ID,R.name,COUNT(DISTINCT BC.Book_isbn)
FROM BookLoans BL
INNER JOIN BookCopy BC ON BL.BookCopy_copy_no = BC.copy_no
INNER JOIN Reader R on BL.Reader_id = R.id
GROUP BY R.ID,R.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BC.Book_isbn) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT isbn) FROM Book)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me like reasonable solution. But I'm getting error: „ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression“ :-(

Comment: Nice that it helped. For ORACLE, you may need some adjustment in Query syntax. But overall the concept should be same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
         SELECT rd.id

           FROM Reader rd,
                Book bk

LEFT OUTER JOIN BookLoans bl
             ON bl.Reader_id = rd.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN BookCopy bc
             ON bc.copy_no = bl.BookCopy_copy_no
            AND bc.Book_isbn = bk.isbn

       GROUP BY rd.id

         HAVING COUNT(bk.isbn) - COUNT(bc.Book_isbn) = 0
```

… but this is definitely not the simpliest query to start learning.